# Make an image fill the background in a Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am trying to beat a bootstrap layout into fitting some requirements I have. The layout started as the default generated by an MVC 5 project template, but I am stuck on getting an image to fill the entire browser width. I need the image to appear as follows:

[image]

If I add a section, with an `img` tag, the image doesn't stretch across the entire screen, but starts 'indented' from the left, and causes the brower so 'overflow' to the right, like:

[image]

The only alternative I can see is to set a background image for `body-content`, but that presents a whole lot of scary positioning issues for the content below the image, and there is quite a lot of that, e.g. below the text "Here's what you'll get' there is still a whole lot of content.

Here is an abridged version of my first attempt:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>s</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <section id="landing">
            <img src="/Content/Images/landing_back.png" alt="The Tax-Free Investment Account" />
        </section>
        <footer>
        ...
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u give us your code or the link to your website? Can't tell you straight from the screenshots. I think it should be possible though.

Comment: @F.Müller I have added what code I can. I tried to omit irrelevant code. Nearly everything is, as I said, the default code generated my the ASP.NET MVC 5 project template. I can't link to the site as it's not yet hosted.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background image of the entire body like this:

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.placecage.com/1000/800");
    background-size:100%;
}
```

However if you are looking to make a specific element full width with Bootstrap then you should use `container-fluid` rather than `container` to hold your content as that element reaches the boundary of your screen width instead of being fixed width.

*Note:* run this snippet in full screen to get the full effect.

```css
.container,
.container-fluid {
  background-image: url("http://www.placecage.com/1000/800");
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Fixed width</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Full width</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks David. My problem with setting the image to the entire body is that I have loads of content I need to show below the image, without a background image. But if that is something I have to deal with by using absolute positioning, then so be it.

Comment: I was making an edit to show you how to do that. How does that look?

Comment: It's worth mentioning here that you can have multiple `container` elements as long as they aren't nested. So add the fluid container above your body content.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidG. Looks like this gives me some solid footing to work with.